# How to use a lambda function as a constructor's parameter to modify the value of the object's own properties

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I want to make the `SceneButton` move to a designated place when it's clicked:

```cpp
SceneButton *scene1_nightstand_pillow = new SceneButton(
    6, 336, "nightstand_pillow", "./res/scene2_nightstand_pillow.png",
    [&scene1_nightstand_pillow, this]()
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "scene2", "pillow");
        //scene1_nightstand_pillow->GetButton()->move(0, 0);
    },
    this);
scene1_nightstand->AddSceneButton(scene1_nightstand_pillow);
```

Why does my program crash when I add the commented out line? (it displays the messagebox correctly)

scene_button.h:

```
#ifndef SCENE_BUTTON_H
#define SCENE_BUTTON_H

#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMovie>
#include <QMessageBox>

class SceneButton : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

private:
  double x, y;
  double size_x, size_y;
  std::string path = "";
  std::string name = "";
  std::function<void()> onClick;
  QPushButton *button;
  QLabel *label;
  QMovie *movie;

public:
  explicit SceneButton(
      double _x, double _y, double _size_x, double _size_y, std::string _name, std::string _path, std::function<void()> _onClick, QWidget *parent = nullptr, std::function<void()> _ondefine = []() {});
  explicit SceneButton(
      double _x, double _y, std::string _name, std::string _path, std::function<void()> _onClick, QWidget *parent = nullptr, std::function<void()> _ondefine = []() {});
  ~SceneButton();
  std::string GetName() { return this->name; }
  std::string GetPath() { return this->path; }
  float GetX(){return x;}
  float GetY(){return y;}
  std::function<void()> GetOnClickFunction() const { return onClick; }
  QPushButton *GetButton() { return button; }
  QLabel *GetLabel() { return label; }


};

#endif
```

scene_button.cc:

```
#include "scene_button.h"

SceneButton::SceneButton(double _x, double _y, double _size_x, double _size_y, std::string _name, std::string _path, std::function<void()> _onClick, QWidget *parent, std::function<void()> _ondefine)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
  this->x = _x;
  this->y = _y;
  this->size_x = _size_x;
  this->size_y = _size_y;
  this->name = _name;
  this->path = _path;
  this->onClick = _onClick;
  QPixmap p(QString::fromStdString(path));
  label = new QLabel(parent);
  button = new QPushButton(parent);

  movie = new QMovie(QString::fromStdString(path));
  label->setMovie(movie);

  QString background_image = "image: url(" + QString::fromStdString(path) + ");";
  QString style_sheet = "background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);";
  label->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
  label->setFixedSize(size_x, size_y);
  label->move(x, y);

  button->setStyleSheet(style_sheet);
  button->setFixedSize(size_x, size_y);
  button->move(x, y);
  button->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
  QObject::connect(movie, &QMovie::frameChanged, [this](int frameNumber)
                   {
    if (frameNumber == movie->frameCount()-1) {
      
    } });
  QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, onClick);
  movie->start();
  _ondefine();
}

SceneButton::SceneButton(double _x, double _y, std::string _name, std::string _path, std::function<void()> _onClick, QWidget *parent, std::function<void()> _ondefine)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
  this->x = _x;
  this->y = _y;
  this->path = _path;
  this->onClick = _onClick;
  this->name = _name;

  QPixmap p(QString::fromStdString(path));

  this->size_x = p.width();
  this->size_y = p.height();
  label = new QLabel(parent);
  button = new QPushButton(parent);

  movie = new QMovie(QString::fromStdString(path));
  label->setMovie(movie);

  QString background_image = "image: url(" + QString::fromStdString(path) + ");";
  QString style_sheet = "background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);";
  label->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
  label->setFixedSize(p.width(), p.height());
  label->move(x, y);

  button->setStyleSheet(style_sheet);
  button->setFixedSize(p.width(), p.height());
  button->move(x, y);
  button->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
  QObject::connect(movie, &QMovie::frameChanged, [this](int frameNumber)
                   {
    if (frameNumber == movie->frameCount()-1) {
      
    } });
  QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, onClick);
  movie->start();
  _ondefine();
}

SceneButton::~SceneButton()
{
  delete button;
  delete label;
  delete movie;
}
```

I thought it was because the lambda function is a parameter of the `SceneButton`'s constructor, and at that time, the construction of `scene1_nightstand_pillow` is not completed yet. Then I tried to write a `SetOnClickFunction`, and call it right after the constructor, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: For **minimal** example code, there should be only one button. So `SceneButton` should not need more than one constructor, and as many parameters as possible should be eliminated. Functionality extraneous to the error should be omitted. So I'd think the only constructor should look more like `SceneButton::SceneButton(std::function<void()> _onClick, QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent), onClick(_onClick)
{
button = new QPushButton(parent);
QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, onClick);
}` -- demonstrate just the error, and drop the rest from your [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SceneButton *scene1_nightstand_pillow = new SceneButton(
      6, 336, "nightstand_pillow", "./res/scene2_nightstand_pillow.png",
      [&scene1_nightstand_pillow, this]()
      {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "scene2", "pillow");
        //scene1_nightstand_pillow->GetButton()->move(0, 0);
      },
      this);
```

It's important to understand the sequence of events here:

1. A `SceneButton` object gets constructed in dynamic scope (this is what `new` is all about).
2. A pointer to this object gets assigned to `scene1_nightstand_pillow`.

Until this `SceneButton` object gets constructed, `scene1_nightstand_pillow` ***is not initialized***. Any attempt to capture it by reference and then use it in the closure that gets passed into the constructor ***and invoked from the constructor*** is doomed to failure. Until the constructor returns, the object is not fully constructed, and `scene1_nightstand_pillow` is not initialized.

The `this` that the lambda function captures must be whatever mysterious object where this code, that constructs a `SceneButton` gets called from, and is not material for the purpose of this discussion.

> I thought it was because the lambda function is a parameter of the `SceneButton`'s constructor, and at that time, the construction of `scene1_nightstand_pillow` is not completed yet.

Correct. The only way for the lambda to access the object that's getting constructed, is for this object to ***get passed to the lambda as a parameter***:

```
[this](SceneButton &obj)
      {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "scene2", "pillow");
        obj.GetButton()->move(0, 0);
      }
```

The constructor parameter becomes a `std::function<void (SceneButton &)>`, and it gets invoked from the constructor as:

```
_ondefine(*this);
```

Comment: *"the closure that gets passed into the constructor ***and invoked from the constructor***"* -- The closure is not invoked from the constructor. You're looking at the `_ondefine` parameter, but the lambda is passed as the `_onClick` parameter (between a string and a pointer).